# Nios II erratic performance, will not connect to target system

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, jtag, nios

I have been working almost a year with the DBC5CEFA7 Board and I have several inconsistency problems with the Nios II processors. I am using to read and write information to other VHDL modules that I execute in the FPGA and validate that the inputs and ouputs are correct and as expected. So every now and then I add/modify/delete PIO ports to accomplish these tasks, I do these modifications in small changes but may be in one of these iterations that the Nios II is generated and my whole project is synthesized and yet when I try to connect to the microcontroller through the JTAG i get the "connected system id has not found" error.

I have tried to regenerate the BSP through the menu "NIOS II > Generate BSP" and through the BSP Editor, i have tried creating a new project, I already reinstalled Quartus and still nothing. I can't find a solutions and I find these errors really frustrating because I cannot continue with the development of my project. The only way I have managed to overcome these error is using a source control manager (GIT) and stepping back until the NIOS architecture works and from there modify it until it works again, but this method is so time consuming. Perhaps somebody has experienced something similar and could point me in the right direction, i would really appreciate it!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

two options are to solve it.

1. Ensure that after generating qsys. Compile quartus ii project and generate bsp. Also ensure that you are downloading the exact .sof file you compiled. If you complied with license and free editions one after other you will get this problem.
2. You can ignore verify system id options in download window for niosii hardware tab.

Hope either will work for you.